# Assigning Name to Dictionary Element

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment, immutability

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys and floats as values.  I have code that looks like

```
For each longtuplekey in dictionary:
    dictionary[longtuplekey]+=func(dictionary[longtuplekey])
    dictionary[longtyplekey]*=func2(dictionary[longtuplekey])
```

I'd like it to shorten it to something like

```
For each longtuplekey in dictionary:
    val=dictionary[longtuplekey]
    val+=func(val)
    val*=func2(val)
```

Except of course that the above code defines val as an immutable float and fails to modify the dictionary entry.  Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I've selected the answer that says "No, there's no explicit way to do this" and provides an alternative.  If anyone comes up with a way to do exactly what I wanted, I will change the answer.

Comment: Create a local variable with a short name for `longtuplekey` only instead. Or write a helper function.

Comment: @Raj The real code doesn't have predefined func and func2, but rather references dictionary[longtuplekey] multiple times so the line ends up fairly long.

Comment: `d = {k: func2(v + func(v)) for k, v in d}`

Comment: @mkrieger1 That helps, but the dictionary name itself is long enough that it makes the line ugly.  If there's no way to do what I'm trying, I can live with it, but it would make my code more understandable to name the element something meaningful while working with it.

Comment: Or: `for val, longtuplekey in dictionary.items(): dictionary[longtuplekey] = func2(val + func(val))`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's a good idea.  I didn't think of dictionary comprehension.  Unfortunately, I am also summing up my changes to return at the end of the function, which I don't think I can (should) do with dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski For your second comment, I think it should be for longtuplekey, val in dictionary.items()

Comment: Then create a short name for the dictionary as well.

Comment: You are correct Kalev.  Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no bulletproof way to make Python recognize that assignments to `val` should update the value in the dictionary too. If you want to update the dict, you'll have to assign back to it. On the bright side, you can reduce the number of required `dictionary[longtuplekey]` usages by iterating over the dict's `items()` rather than just its keys.

```
for longtuplekey, val in d.items():
    val += func(val)
    val *= func2(val)
    d[longtuplekey] = val
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use 2 assignments here, just do both funcs inside the imul assignment and use `dict.items` to loop over the keys and values simultaneously:

```
for longtuplekey, val in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[longtuplekey] *= func2(val + func(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for longtuplekey in dictionary:
    val = dictionary[longtuplekey]
    val += func(val)
    val *= func2(val)
    dictionary[longtuplekey] = val
```